# Question about incrementing data value, from a specific collection in mongodb with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, numbers, increment

So I followed a tutorial which has taught me some things about nodejs and mongodb. I now know how to insert new data from the server in to my database.

But what I can't seem to figure out is how to update existing data in a collection.  I have searched on a lot of places but sadly no clear answer for me. I am a little of a noob still with this so excuse me if i say things that are probably wrong.

So this is what I've tried to set up:

Code from my Controller.js:

```js
      app.get("/button", function(req, res) {
      mongo.connect(url_monitor, function (err, db) {
          assert.equal(null, err);
          db.numbers.update({ $inc: { number: -2}})
          getData(res);
        })
  })
  
}
```

I am using the MVC model that has the: controller, model and view.  So all pages in the view folder are .ejs files. I am also using jQuery and ajax to send a request to the controller.

button.js:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btn1').on('click', function(){
    var number =  {number: 0}
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/button',
      data: number,
      success: function(number){
        //do something with the data via front-end framework
        location.reload();
        alert('It works')
      }
    });
});
})
```

button.ejs:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/assets/button.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Todo List</title>
    
  <link href="/assets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Button test</h1>
<button id="btn1">Increase number</button>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically what I am trying to achieve is that once I press a button somewhere on a page, it would increase/decrease a value in the database in one of the specific collections. I am kinda lost with this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a very long time, i finally found the solution. If anyone else is having this issue then refer to this link: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/updateOne